# Encoding problem when reading from a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine, encoding

I'm reading text from CSV file and had to use an specific encoding to read spanish characters (tildes), but this encoding doesn't work for the ' characters that my CSV file contains.

This is the code sample:

```
var myString = File.ReadAllText("path"), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

I wanted to read all characters in my CSV file but failed with special characters. Need an enconding that reads tildes (spanish characters) and also up-commas (').

Comment: You should not need to use encoding reading a file.  The encoding should default to UTF-8.  If you are not getting correct characters try changing the font to one that works with Spanish letters.

Comment: the single quotes (up commas made me laugh) should also be read, however, if they have been replaced (much as word replaces quotes with fancy quotes so they look like 66 and 99) then again those will be less obvious because they may not show depending on the font.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask].  Then, [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share (sanitized if necessary) a part of your `csv` file in hexadecimal (`hexdump "path"`).